# USB to RS-232 to USB

Tags: usb, rs232

I have a system where there is USB slave device that is in a rotating structure behind a slipring. I need to pass the signal through the slipring (we only have 4 "wires") and onto a computer. Due to the long distance and noisy environment I'd like to convert the USB signal to RS-232 or 485 but my understanding is that USB to RS-232 dongles do not work on slave devices.

How do I do this? There are USB to cat5 but I only have four conductors.

Comment: why wouldn't a usb to RS232 device work? There is no reason why not.

Comment: Because the device is a usb Peripheral,  not host.

Comment: Exactly the Peripheral has no idea about an FTDI chip or the equivalent

Comment: Even if you will manage to find usb-serial converter for the device, it won't help, since (probably) your device is not using simple serial protocol, but is using some specific USB profile, right?

Comment: How long is your line? The best thing you can do is to use some USB repeater there are some cheap ones out there..). EDIT: Oh..missed the slip ring part..

Comment: why not have a host device up on the other side of the slip ring and it can act as a pass-through/bridge to the USB end device somehow? so it would go USB end device -> USB host with RS232 converter -> slip ring -> RS232 to USB converter -> PC

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is straightforwardly doable, the speeds are too different. Best you could manage is:

- put a microcontroller in host mode on the slave side
- write drivers for the USB device
- write a serial protocol for the actions you want to perform
- have the PC communicate with the microcontroller over the slip ring.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any COTS solutions, but there are many chips that can function as a USB host and also have a UART interface. The [FTDI Vinculum](http://www.ftdichip.com/Products/ICs/VNC2.htm) is just one example, but there are many others, including the [Microchip PIC32](http://www.microchip.com/pagehandler/en-us/family/32bit/), or indeed, pretty much any microcontroller with a USB host or OTG hardware interface.

Such a device could be programmed to act as a host to your USB peripheral, and then communicate using UART protocol through the slip rings to a standard USB-to-UART adapter attached to your host.

If this is a one-off project, you could even use a board-level product such as RaspberryPi or BeagleBone to perform this function.

Comment: This was my backup plan. Use a Pi to collect the data on the USB Peripheral and then send it out over RS232. Doesn't look as if there is an OTS solution (google hasn't shown anything)

Comment: There are smaller and slightly cheaper solutions than a $25 dollar pi. But that's pretty cheap

Answer (score 0):

I have put an USB camera in the squirrel house in my garden. It connects to my PC via an USB-over-UTP converter set (UTSP cable length 30 meters or so). Something like [this](http://www.networktechinc.com/usbc5.html)

[image]

But I think it requires 8 (or maybe 6) wires, not 4.